# Silverlight - How to close a page in Navigation Framework

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit, silverlight-5.0

How do you close a page on a Frame when using Navigation Framework? On a Frame I can only find methods GoBack and GoFoward, but no Close or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do that straight, but you can approximate it by using a blank page and collapsing the Frame.

In other words: create an empty `Page`, with minimal XAML. When you want to 'close' your current page, navigate to your empty page instead (to unload your current page) and set the `Visibility` of your `Frame` to `Collapsed`. This should do what you want.